# Pycharm cannot suggest import for django.test

Tags: python, django

Not suggest any class in `django.test`, but worked in `django.http`.

How to fix it ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think that's problem with Django itself, just Pycharm bug. You can send bug report for that, but tbh import for django TestCase is not that long and easy to remember + you will most likely add own TestCase more suitable for your project

Answer (score -1):

you have to import the @classmethod for the test class
For example :

```
class YourTestClass(TestCase):
    @classmethod
```

This [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Testing) will help you to understand